# How to redirect user to another page if the user is logged in - WordPress Elementor Page Builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a registration form using Elementor Page Builder. Now, I want to redirect the user to a different page if he/she is trying to access that registration page after logging in.

Is there any Elementor hook available for that? I know the WordPress function called **is_user_logged_in()**.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
     
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 12 ) ) 
    {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 32 ) );
        die;
    }
     
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

You should get the ids of the page where the form is and the id of the page you want to redirect the user to.

Code goes in your child theme functions.php file

Reference: [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#:%7E:text=template_redirect%20Action)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Content Area Not Found' error might appear on Elementor designed sites when you use that snippet and try to edit page of ID 12 (*in your example*) in certain cases.

To avoid this, add the following code before the if-statement of your snippet:

```
if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode() ) {
        return;
    }
```